# How to load a .js-file depending on screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How can we load a specific Javascript-file using the media queries from the WordPress themefolder (wp-content/themename/js/file.js)

Whe would only like to load grid.js when using a tablet or a desktop browser.

Answer (score 1):

You should load your grid.js asynchronous:

```js
function is_touch_device()
{
          
  return !!('ontouchstart' in window);
           
} 

function loadGridJs() 
{

  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script'); 
  scriptTag.src = "//wp-content/themename/js/grid.js"; 
  scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  scriptTag.async = true;  
  var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  headTag.appendChild(scriptTag);

}

if (is_touch_device())
{

  loadGridJs();

}
```

See:

[Javascript asynchron nachladen](http://daschmi.de/javascript-asynchron-laden/), 
[Touchgeräte erkennen](http://daschmi.de/mobiletouch-geraete-per-javascript-erkennen/)